# Line separator in Java N/IO?

Tags: java, nio

How do I insert new line when writing to a txt file using `java.nio.file` ?
The following code produces a txt file with one line `ABCDEF`, instead of two separate lines `ABC` and `DEF`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        final Path PATH = Paths.get("test.txt");
        String test = "ABC\nDEF";
        Files.write(PATH, test.getBytes());
    }
```

Comment: No it doesn't. It produces a file with ABC, a line feed, and DEF. it might read as a single line in some programs, but Java will read it as two lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beginning with Java 7, you should use [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) instead of hard coding `\n`, since the line separator really depends on which machine the code will run.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    final Path PATH = Paths.get("test.txt");
    String test = "ABC" + System.lineSeparator() + "DEF";
    Files.write(PATH, test.getBytes());
}
```

If you are still using Java 6 or older, the same is achieved with `System.getProperty("line.separator")` ([see Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)).

Comment: Assumes Java 7, which is still not a guarantee here on Stack Overflow. Still got my up-vote anyway.

Comment: @Andreas I edited my post to add a solution for Java <= 6.

Comment: OP uses the `Files` class, therefore Java 7 can be safely assumed.

Answer (score 1):

Other options to use the system line separator:

Use another overload of `Files.write` which expects an `Iterable` of strings (`CharSequence`, to be exact) and writes each of them on its own line using the system line separator. This is most helpful if you already store the lines in a collection.

```
Files.write(PATH, Arrays.asList("ABC","DEF"),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

(It's better to specify the character set rather than rely on the default, which is what happens when using `String.getBytes()` without a character set).

Or use `String.format`:

```
String test = String.format("ABC%nDEF");
```

`Formatter` (which `String.format` uses) interprets `%n` as the system line separator.

This approach is backward-compatible all the way back to Java 1.5. But of course, the `Files` class did not exist before Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing to @Tunaki, if you want two lines, only insert another line:

> String test = "ABC" + System.lineSeparator() + System.lineSeparator() + "DEF";